# SAS to access blob container (azure/python)

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

I want to give limited access to a single container in my account without sharing my entire storage account key.  I generated a Shared Access Signature in Azure Storage Explorer specific to the container.

[container right-click & generate SAS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUKrF.png)

[example of output from generate SAS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1PDe.png)

When I attempt to use the blockblobservice to list files I get the following errors.  Same sort of error when using get_blob_to_path.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, BlobPermissions

sas_container = 'nwe-statements'
sas_token = '?st=2019-12-05T21%3A09%3A12Z&se=2020-01-31T21%3A13%3A00Z&sp=racwdl&sv=2018-03-28&sr=c&sig=YLk2UWxPcqkDl5a8nWtBYcw%3DxWuAsfFI1ch5TwrbAxvk'
example_file = '1470-4126.pdf'

def sas_list():
    blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='pretend',sas_token=sas_token)
    blob_list = blob_service.list_blobs(sas_container)
    print(blob_list)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/brett/jetco/django_jetco/O365/nwe_statements/blob_connect.py", line 24, in 
>       sas_list()
>     File "/home/brett/jetco/django_jetco/O365/nwe_statements/blob_connect.py", line 11, in sas_list
>       blob_list = blob_service.list_blobs(sas_container)
>     File "/home/brett/jetco/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py", line 1214, in list_blobs
>       resp = self._list_blobs(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/brett/jetco/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py", line 1285, in _list_blobs
>       return self._perform_request(request, _convert_xml_to_blob_list, operation_context=_context)
>     File "/home/brett/jetco/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/storage/storageclient.py", line 280, in _perform_request
>       raise ex
>     File "/home/brett/jetco/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/storage/storageclient.py", line 248, in _perform_request
>       raise ex
>     File "/home/brett/jetco/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/storage/storageclient.py", line 235, in _perform_request
>       _http_error_handler(HTTPError(response.status, response.message, response.headers, response.body))
>     File "/home/brett/jetco/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/storage/_error.py", line 114, in _http_error_handler
>       raise AzureHttpError(message, http_error.status)
>   azure.common.AzureHttpError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
>   `AuthenticationFailed`Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
>   RequestId:2d2370dc-f01e-0028-0fb3-ab47c9000000
>   Time:2019-12-05T21:33:23.3062345ZSignature did not match. String to sign used was racwdl
>
> 2020-01-31T21:13:00Z
>   /blob/pretend/nwe-statements
>
> 2018-03-28

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, the issue was caused by the package, please uninstall the `azure-storage` which is old and install `azure-storage-blob 2.1.0`, then it will work fine.

```
pip uninstall azure-storage
pip install azure-storage-blob==2.1.0
```

[image]

[image]

Besides, you should note there is a new version [`v12`](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/12.1.0/) of `azure-storage-blob`, which is different from the [`v2.1`](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/2.1.0/) version.

v12 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python

v2.1 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python-legacy

Comment: Joy - You popped my cherry here on stackoverflow and the consequences for such an honor is you will get no satisfaction... because I need 15 reputation points to mark your answer as correct.

Solution worked immediately!

Answer (score 0):

Found a working version inspired by the other answers here, using ContainerClient

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient

credential="?sv=2021-04-10&st=2022-12-07T07%3A56%3A37Z&se=2022-12-08T07%3A56%3A37Z&sr=c&sp=racwdl&sig=3ge............."

cc = ContainerClient(account_url="https://yourAccount.blob.core.windows.net",container_name="yourOwnCointainerName",credential=credential)

#Example - List all blobs:
for i in cc.list_blobs():
    print(i)

#Example - Upload file
with open('file.json','rb') as data:
    cc.upload_blob(data=data,name="file.json")
```